# `basename` argument not specified, and could ' \

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I am getting the below error again and again.I am trying to solve it from 
morning but nothing is happening.

> assert queryset is not None, '`basename` argument not specified, and
>   could ' \ AssertionError: `basename` argument not specified, and could
>   not automatically determine the name from the viewset, as it does not
>   have a `.queryset` attribute.

models.py

```
class Language(models.Model):
    A = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    B = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True)
    C = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    D = models.TextField(max_length=256)
    E = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

serializers.py

```
class LanguageSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Language
        fields = ("__all__")
```

views.py

```
class LanguageView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Language.objects.all()
    serializer_class = LanguageSerializer
```

urls.py

```
router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register('ln/languages', views.LanguageView)
```

There are many more models(tables) in models.py, Every other model(table) is

working fine for getting results but Language model(table) is givin the error

> assert queryset is not None, '`basename` argument not specified, and
>   could ' \ AssertionError: `basename` argument not specified, and could
>   not automatically determine the name from the viewset, as it does not
>   have a `.queryset` attribute.

Comment: What you posted here should work. Either you have a typo in your real code or another view registration is failing.

Comment: You can try this: `router.register('ln/languages', views.LanguageView, basename='languages')`. However, it would be just a test, I agree with @Linovia, that there is some sort of typo. you can also try to remove the `ln/` in the `router.register('ln/languages', views.LanguageView)`, `/` separators can always be tricky.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Give a try

```
router.register('ln/languages', views.LanguageView, basename='ln-languages')
```

or

```
router.register('ln/languages', views.LanguageView, basename='languages')
```

More detail you can check the documentation [django-rest-framework-routers](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/routers/)