# `basename` argument not specified - DJANGO REST Framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm new in Django stuff and would like to build an API Server.

However, when I register the ModelViewSet I get the error shown in the title.

Model:

```py
from django.db import models
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError

class User(models.Model):
    telegram_id = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    mail = models.CharField(max_length=100, default="None")
    password = models.CharField(max_length=100, default="None")
    is_group = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    priority = models.IntegerField(default=10)
    max_watches = models.IntegerField(default=5)
    current_watches = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    notification_rate = models.IntegerField(default=3600)
    watches = models.ManyToManyField('Url', through="Watch")

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.current_watches > self.max_watches:
            raise ValidationError("Límite de enlaces alcanzado")
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.telegram_id
```

Serializer:

```py
from rest_framework import serializers
from hermes.models import User


class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = '__all__'
```

ViewSet:

```py
from rest_framework import viewsets

import hermes.models as models
import hermes.serializers.UserSerializer as UserSerializer

class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = models.User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
```

router:

```
from hermes.ViewSets import UserViewSet
from rest_framework import routers

router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'users/', UserViewSet)
```

router in app:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from hermes.urls import router

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('api/', include(router.urls))
]
```

I have also added the basename param at the end of the router as it suggested me but is fails again saying that it has no attribute get_extra_actions. And when I define that method it still raises the same error. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Ive read several issues with something like my question but didnt help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55296191/basename-argument-not-specified-and-could

Answer (score 0):

In your definition of viewset, remove models and redefine as below:

```
class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
```

Also there is no need of ending your url patterns with a '/', can drop it
So `router.register(r'users/', UserViewSet)` should be:
`router.register(r'users', UserViewSet)`

If you see the root APIs you will notice there are double // otherwise